# What is the difference between zk-SNARK and NIZK?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am not exactly sure what is the difference between zk-SNARK and NIZK? Are NIZK not succinct? If so, why Pinocchio protocol considered itself a NIZK although they have succinct proof?

I tried Google but couldn't find the exact difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ZK-SNARK is a NIZK (more precisely, a non-interactive zero-knowledge argument of knowledge in the common reference string model) which is succinct, meaning that both the *proof size* and the *verification time* grow sublinearly with the witness size.

Therefore, every ZK-SNARK is in particular a NIZK (but not all NIZKs are ZK-SNARKs).

Pinocchio provide a ZK-SNARK (using their general scheme that targets arbitrary NP computation), which is therefore also a NIZK.